# using usb_cam from remote computer. Cannot identify '/dev/video0': 2, No such file or directory

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, usb-camera, camera, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

My configuration is the following:

1. ROS-master computer: Nvidia TX2 with Ubuntu 18.04, ROS melodic and package usb_cam installed on it
   , and Logitech USB camera connected to it through the USB port
2. The computer which I try to start the command  `roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch` from:
   Ubuntu 18.04

I've found one similar question on this forum: #q284015.

**But** my problem is a little bit different because my configuration includes **2 computers**.

Here is the situation:

I `ssh` on board computer (**Nvidia TX2** with Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS melodic) and start `roscore` on it
and after that start this command on my computer:

```
roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch
```

So, ROS-Master is different computer from the one where I start the command.
But I don't have any issues with connecting to ROS-master.
And `roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch` works perfectly fine, when I do it locally, on **Nvidia TX2** which is ROS-master computer.

I have an error when I try to run it on my laptop which isn't ROS-master and after the following command:

```
roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch
```

I have this error message:

```
[ERROR] [1676393342.653244327]: Cannot identify '/dev/video0': 2, No such file or directory
[usb_cam-1] process has died [pid 3741, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node __name:=usb_cam __log:=/....log
```

I can see `/dev/video0` device on my ROS-master computer, so, the device totally exists and, as I mentioned above, I can run this command locally on the ROS-master computer, the problem is only with running the command from the remote computer.

Looks like some problem with the permission of the remote user, but I don't understand how to add permission for the remote user:

> Try adding yourself to the user group
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
> ```

Mean, this advice looks like something which can help me, but I don't understand how to apply it for the remote user/computer

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412501/using-usb_cam-from-remote-computer.-cannot-identify-%27/dev/video0%27:-2,-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [kozinovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/97994/kozinovsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2023-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to start a `.launch` file which requires a usb camera on a PC which doesn't have the camera connected?

If that's the case, the problem would not be permissions, but the fact the camera is connected to the other device/PC.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kozinovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/97994/kozinovsky/) on 2023-02-15**:
Ops, that is exactly what I am trying to do. Thank you, I didn't know that this **launch** file can be run only locally (on ROS-master PC).
But then, how, using **usb_cam** package can I see a camera picture on the remote laptop which has access to the ROS-master PC with a connected USB camera to it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-02-15**:
Start `image_view` (or whatever you want to use to see the `sensor_msgs/Image` stream) on your laptop after starting the `.launch` file which starts `usb_cam` on the host *with* the camera?

ROS is networked/distributed by default. You just have to [configure it correctly](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines).

**Comment by [kozinovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/97994/kozinovsky/) on 2023-02-15**:
Thank you so much! That is what I was looking for. Just checked it on my setup - it works. Thanks again!